# Can't update post meta using array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to use `update_post_meta()` and save a post meta from 
Array.

Example:

```
$thing_to_add = array( '507' => 500, '366' => 550 );
update_post_meta($post_id, 'thing_to_add', $thing_to_add);
```

I want to save the whole `$thing_to_add` in my post meta, but it is not saving it . If `$thing_to_add` is a string, it updates. But I want to save the array. How can I do that?

I've included my full code below.

```
<input type="number" name="inventory_id[507]" />
<input type="number" name="inventory_id[366]" />
$inventory_ids = $_POST['inventory_id'];
//var_dump shows this - array(2) { [507]=> string(2) "500" [366]=> string(2) "550" }
update_post_meta($post_id, 'inventory_ids', $inventory_ids);
```

**Solved:** From DavidWinder's comment below, I just noticed it automatically serializes the array and saves it in DB. However it doesn't show on post edit page.

Comment: probably you should not do what you are doing. But just to bypass the obstacle you have you can try: `update_post_meta($post_id, 'inventory_ids', is_array($inventory_ids)?implode(',',$inventory_ids):$inventory_ids);`

Comment: How do you know it is not saved? remember that is the value is array it is automatically serialized - do you use `get_post_meta` with flag true for the array extraction? Maybe this will helps:https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/243238/how-to-update-post-meta-value-as-array

Comment: @Alex I need to get them back, so can't implode the commas.

Comment: @DavidWinder Just saw it actually serialized the array and saved it in Database. The meta wasn't showing on post edit page, so I was worried about it. Didn't have in mind that it might serialize the array and not display on edit page. Thank you. It's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) can save data as array but it is automatically serialized.

If you want to get the value back as array you should use the flag `$single` of the [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

In your case:

```
<input type="number" name="inventory_id[507]" />
<input type="number" name="inventory_id[366]" />
$inventory_ids = $_POST['inventory_id'];

//var_dump shows this - array(2) { [507]=> string(2) "500" [366]=> string(2) "550" }

// save the meta
update_post_meta($post_id, 'inventory_ids', $inventory_ids);

// get the meta
$inventory_ids_from_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'inventory_ids', true ); // this is the true flag
```