# Generate unique random number on woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item based on custom field

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to generate a unique random number for each woocommerce order item based on a custom field i have set for each product.

For example, the custom field `$drawnumbers` is set to 1000 when creating the product and for each item quantity in the cart it needs to randomly generate a number between 1 and the value of `$drawnumbers` and set the value as a custom field `meta_key_value` for each order item. I've forced the cart to split the qty for each product as a separate cart item.

Once the number has been allocated to an order item, i need to store it in an array called `$chosennumbers` so it can't be allocated again. I've done this by adding the number into an array and using the `array_diff()` function.

When testing it, It randomly generates a number but i don't think it's storing it into the `$drawnumbers` custom field correctly as when I look at the order, the meta fields are displaying different numbers to the `print_r(get_field('draw_no'));` on the single product page.

The code I have is like so:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'lottery_ticket_items', 20, 4 );

function lottery_ticket_items( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order )
{
    $numberallocated = array();
    $_p = $item->get_product();
    $product_id =  $_p->get_id();
    $drawnumbers = get_field('draw_no', $product_id);
    $qty = get_field('maximum_entries', $product_id);
    $array = range(1, $qty);
    $result = array_diff($array, $drawnumbers);
    $key = 'meta_key_value';

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_product ) {
    // Get the product ID
    $number = array_rand($result, 1);
    $numberallocated[] = $number;
    $product_id = $item_product->get_product_id();
    $item->add_meta_data( $key , $number , true ); 

}              

    update_field('draw_no', $numberallocated, $product_id);

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'lottery_display_tickets', 5 );

function lottery_display_tickets() {
 print_r(get_field('draw_no'));
}
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You are storing array in `draw_no` - did you try get them with `true` in argument? maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53914697/6487675) will help

Comment: Hi David, i think advanced custom fields automatically does this. When i print_r the draw_no i can see an array being returned but the values aren't the same as the order item meta field :/